# Devise sign_in_and_redirect causes rspec test to fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, omniauth

I'm sort of new to TDD, so you'll have to excuse me if this is obvious, but I've got a login system using Devise and Omniauth that works perfectly in development, but for some reason, when I run my rspec test, it fails.

I'm testing the create action for my authentications controller

```
class AuthenticationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    omniauth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
    if authentication
      flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully"
      sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)
    else
      user = User.find_by_email(omniauth['info']['email']) || User.new(:email => omniauth['info']['email'], :fname => omniauth['info']['first_name'], :lname => omniauth['info']['last_name']) 
      user.authentications.build(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])
      if user.save :validate => false
        flash[:notice] = "Login successful"
        sign_in_and_redirect(:user, user)
      else
        flash[:notice] = "Login failed"
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    end
  end
end
```

with this rspec test

```
describe "GET 'create'" do
    before(:each) do
      request.env['omniauth.auth'] = { "provider" => "facebook", "uid" => "1298732", "info" => { "first_name" => "My", "last_name" => "Name", "email" => "myemail@email.com" } }
    end

    it "should create a user" do
      lambda do
        get :create
      end.should change(User, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
```

When I run the test I get

```
Failure/Error: get :create
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/authentications_controller.rb:13:in `create'
```

Indeed, if I remove the sign_in_and_redirect statement, the test passes.  Interestingly though, using sign_in instead of sign_in_and_redirect fails as well.

Anyone know why this might happen?  Especially since when I create an account myself in development it works fine...

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Pretty sure I solved my own problem.

Apparently, in order to use the Devise's sign_in method within a test you must make a call to:

    include Devise::TestHelpers

After including it, my problem went away, and everything seems to functioning correctly.

Answer (score 1):

[How To: Controllers and Views tests with Rails 3 (and rspec)](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29)

> Controller specs won’t work out of the box if you’re using any of devise’s utility methods.
>
> As of rspec-rails-2.0.0 and devise-1.1, the best way to put devise in your specs is simply to add the following into spec_helper:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```